# Disable Jquery function

Tags: jquery, function

I have two functions in JQuery

```
jQuery.fn.funct1= function(a,b,c){
 //code ...load() by scrolling from results.php
 //  in ul#total_results (sql="SELECT ABC") 100 RESULTS
    //$("#total_results").append(data);
                             }

jQuery.fn.funct2= function(m,n,p){
//code ...load() by scrolling from results.php 
//   in ul#total_results (sql="SELECT MNP") 30 RESULTS
    //$("#total_results").append(data);                                          }
```

I trigger the first function to appears by default in the page

```
  $(document).ready(function() {    
       $("#total_results").funct1(a,b,c);
    });
```

But once I click the second anchor to run the second function, appears results loaded in the first function while scrolling the page. I want the first function to be disabled while the another is working and vice versa.

```
<a onclick="$('#total_results').funct1(a,b,c);">Show results funct 1</a>
 <a onclick="$('#total_results').funct2(m,n,p);">Show results funct 2</a>

 <ul id=total_results></ul>
```

I want clicking in the first anchor to show the results of `funct1` and clicking the second anchor to show the results of `funct2`.

I tried a boolean, creating a `noShowFunct1=true & noShowFunct1=false ;` but nothing, as well as `jQuery.fn.funct1=null` but nothing. tried to do `window.onload= funct1`, and then `window.onload=null` after clicking the anchor with `funct2` it also didn't work. This is the updated fiddle of the structure, https://jsfiddle.net/2mkc4w3e/3/

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean; is `funct1` and `funct2` simply _appending_ content to `#total_results`? You don't need to _disable_ a function, just overwrite the contents in `#total_results`.

Comment: I did, I need to disable funct1 which runs by default, because once I click the anchor that activate funct2, and once I scroll the page, the funct1 start loading content again, so in this moment both functions works and load content in  `#total_results` at the same time.

Comment: I understand that you mean using `.html()` or `replaceWith()` instead of `append()`?

Comment: It's not easy to help with no executive sample. Please make a fiddle

Comment: You call `results.php` *twice* in `$.fn.funct1`? Why is that?

Comment: Because the first calling is to show the first group of results and the second calling is for the next groups of results after scrolling the page.

Comment: But you call exactly the same PHP page, so it will return exactly the same content twice, no?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2mkc4w3e/3/ Yes, I improved the coding, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is not correct:

```
<a onclick="$("#total_results").funct1(a,b,c);">Show results funct 1</a>
<a onclick="$("#total_results").funct2(m,n,p);">Show results funct 2</a>
```

You would have to escape the double quotes, or else use single quotes instead:

```
<a onclick="$('#total_results').funct1(a,b,c);">Show results funct 1</a>
<a onclick="$('#total_results').funct2(m,n,p);">Show results funct 2</a>
```

But it would be even better if you would separate your handler code from your HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="a1">Show results funct 1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2">Show results funct 2</a>

<script>
     $('#a1').click(function () {
         $('#total_results').funct1(a,b,c);
     });
     $('#a2').click(function () {
         $('#total_results').funct2(m,n,p);
     });
</script>
```

```js
$.fn.funct1 = function(a,b,c) {
    $(this).text('a='+a+'\nb='+b+'\nc=' +c);
}
$.fn.funct2 = function(m,n,p) {
    $(this).text('m='+m+'\nn='+n+'\np=' +p);
}

var a=1,b=1,c=1,m=2,n=2,p=2;

$('#a1').click(function () {
    $('#total_results').funct1(a,b,c);
});
$('#a2').click(function () {
    $('#total_results').funct2(m,n,p);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="a1">Show results funct 1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2">Show results funct 2</a>
<div id="total_results"></div>
```

#### "Stopping" asynchronous code

You provided this code (which had some errors) in a fiddle, to which I added a variable `currentFunc` to make sure only one of the two function can write to the `total_results` element.

```
var curr_func = null;

$.fn.funct1= function(total_groups){
    loading=false;
    total_groups=0;
    curr_func = 1; // remember that this function is activated
    $("#total_results").load("results.php",function(){
        if (curr_func !== 1) return; // other function is active! 
        total_groups++
    })

    If(/* scrolling page criteria or so*/ ) {
        loading = true;
        $.post("results.php", function() {
            if (curr_func !== 1) return; // other function is active! 
            $("#total_results").append(data);
        }
    }
}
```

You would do the same in the other function, but then set and test on the value 2.

Add the `if (curr_func ...)` test in every asynchronous code you may have triggered from either function (i.e. in callback functions).

Comment: Thanks by helping with the sintax, I was recommended to use `.on()` method too, but my real problem is how to disable one function while the another one is running and vice versa. Realize that both functions depicted are functions that loads content by scrolling the page

Comment: When you say *is running*, please realise that nothing else can run in JavaScript at the same time, so maybe your functions are performing asynchronous actions, like with animations. Without seeing your jQuery plugin code, it is hard to help you with this.

Comment: See my update which gives an idea on how to "stop" the other "running" function (it is not actually running, but it could get a callback call).

Comment: Thanks you, so what you mean is to stop the loop `total_groups++` in case the function is not the activated one, ok, thanks you Ill try it.

Comment: Indeed, you get out of any code that gets called inside *funct1* when in the mean time *funct2* was called. The same of course in the opposite sense. The variable *curr_func* keeps track of which function was called last.